# Does the ratio of two classes matter in classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I am building a sentiment analysis program using some tweets i have gathered. The labeled data which i have gathered would go through a neural network which classifies them into two classes, positive and negative.

The data is still being labeled. So far i have observed that the positive category has very small number of observations.

The records for positive category in my training set could be about 5% of the training data set (the same ratio could reflect in the population as well).

Would this create problems in the final "program" ?
Size of the data set is about 5000 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, yes it can. There are two things to consider:

1. 5% of 5000 is 250. Thus you will try to model data distribution of your class based on just 250 samples. This might be orders of magnitude to small for neural network. Consequently you might need 40x more data to have a representative sample of your data. While you can easily reduce the majority class through subsampling, without the big risk of destroing the structure - there is no way to get "more structure" from less points (you can replicate points, add noise etc. but this does not add structure, this just adds assumptions).
2. Class imbalance can also lead to convergence to naive solutions, like "always False" which has 95% accuracy. Here you can simply play around with the cost function to make it more robust to imbalance (in particular - train splits suggested by @PureW is nothing else like "black box" method of trying to change the loss function so it has bigger weight on minority class. When you have access to your classifier loss, like in NN you should not due this - but instead change the cost function and still keep all the data).

Comment: Since the data points being tweets here, i will have to collect more of them as you point out. So collect more data for the class with less records?

Comment: I would recommend gathering with "true ratio" as long as the smallest class is big enough to start processing. It is easier to discard data afterwards, then to get new ones, thus if it is possible - just gather more of everything. If for some reason it is too expensive - keep track of true prior and focus on minority class, and later on use this prior (5% vs 95%) in your classifier as well as in testing

Answer (score 2):

Without even splits of the different classes, you may want to introduce weights in your loss function such that errors in the smaller class are deemed more important.

Another solution, since 5000 samples may or may not be much data depending on your problem,  could be to sample more datasets. You basically take this set of 5000 samples, and sample datapoints from it such that you have a new dataset with even split of the classes. This means the new dataset is only 10% of your original dataset. But it is evenly split between the classes. You can redo this sampling  many times and end up with several datasets, useful in [bootstrap aggregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating).

Comment: I have seen sentiment analysis done with 2B of data. So i guess 5k is not much compared with that.
I like your idea of having the training set to be evenly split. Will note that.